# Как сделать отправку сообщения в aiogram внутри условия

Tags: python, aiogram, python-telegram-bot

```
if message.text == "Создать напоминание⌚":
    await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Создать напоминание⌚", reply_markup=nav.napominanie)
```

Каждый раз когда бот получает сообщение от пользователя `Создать напоминание⌚` мне нужно, чтобы он отправлял через определенное время какое-либо сообщение.

Пробовал `AsyncIOScheduler` - Но, он отрабатывает один раз. То есть бот отправлял сообщение как надо, только если условие еще раз будет соблюдаться, бот уже не отправит сообщение повторно.

Пробовал `datetime` - напрямую в условии, но получалось так, что datetime полностью замораживал бота на некоторое время.

Comment: Не нужно писать капслоком.

Answer (score 0):

Можешь через `sleep` это сделать.

```
if message.text == "Создать напоминание⌚":
sleep(1)
await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Создать напоминание⌚", 
reply_markup=nav.napominanie)
```